# Как вернуть ссылку на указатель char?

Tags: c++

У меня была функция `std::string& getStr();` я решил переделать ее в char*

```
char sms[120];
char* &getStr()
{

    return sms;
}
```

как мне правильно ее вернуть?

Comment: возвращайте просто указатель, и он будет указывать на sms.  Ссылаться на  него не зачем

Comment: В *данном случае* просто `char * getStr(){ return sms; }`. Но только не `char * getStr(){ char sms[120]; return sms; }`!!

Comment: Дело в том, чтобы возвращать ссылку на указать, следует где-то хранить указатель, чтобы он продолжал жить и после выхода из функции. А тут никаких указателей вообще нет и ссылаться не на что. `char * psz_str{sms}; char * & getStr(void) { return psz_str; }` Ну а вообще лучше используйте `std::string` вместо сырых массивов и указателей.

Comment: @user7860670 Задумался. А зачем вообще может пригодиться *возвращать ссылку на указатель*? Передавать указатель по ссылке - без вопросов, а возвращать?...

Comment: @HarryfromKiev Даже не знаю, разве что геттер какой-нибуть для обертки, работающей с С структурами.